# Azure app works on dev fabric but not when deployed

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, azure-web-roles, acs

I've recently incorporated Access Control Service into our app. And it works 100% fine in dev fabric (no exceptions being thrown). However, when running this on the actual azure website it fails to load the website.

I've added in logging calls throughout the website, and the only ones that fire are on the start and the end of the WebRole in the OnStart() method. I've added logging into the controller it should be hitting and it is never called. I've also added logging into the "InitializePropertiesFromConfiguration" method that is overridden in my custom WSFederationAuthenticationModule, which has lead me to believe that it is having problems doing something in the web config (adding in my custom STS handler and the like). Below is the web.config of my application, if anyone has any idea what could be causing issues such as these, or even at least something to try I would be very grateful. To make matters worse, a work firewall issue means I can't remote into the azure machine to see what errors are thrown to the windows log. I'm at a loss what could be the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en" uiCulture="en"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="TBX.Common.Web"/>
        <add namespace="TBX.Pulse.Web"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="TBX.Pulse.Web.Authentication.CustomWSFederationAuthenticationModule, TBX.Pulse.Web"/>
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="TBX.Pulse.Web.Authentication.CustomWSFederationAuthenticationModule, TBX.Pulse.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TBX.Pulse.Web.Scripts.ButtonClickAnimationAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="federatedServiceHostConfiguration" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.ConfigureServiceHostBehaviorExtensionElement, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <claimsAuthorizationManager type="TBX.Pulse.Web.Authorization.CustomClaimsAuthorizationManager" />
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="TBX.Pulse.Web.Authentication.CustomClaimsAuthenticationManager" />

      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <remove type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add type="TBX.Pulse.Web.Authentication.CustomSecurityTokenHandler, TBX.Pulse.Web"/>
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <serviceCertificate>
        <certificateReference x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="PulseLoginCert" />
      </serviceCertificate>
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: 
After messing about with this I've found 2 issues, one I've fixed another is still left to resolve:
The first issue was that the web config needed this:

because I've switched over to https

The second issue has to do with loading in the certificate:

Commenting out this portion of code, it runs fine. With it still there it doesn't work. The obvious issue is then that it cannot load this cert. I've tried loading by thumbprint instead, to no avail. My best guess is that the storeLocation or storeName is incorrect on azure. I've added the cert into the "Certificates" folder, but it can't find it. I'll mess about with these and report back.

EDIT2: 
Found the cause of the second issue:
I forgot to add the certificate to the web role, this site was a big help to figure that out:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/12/01/how-to-add-an-https-endpoint-to-a-windows-azure-cloud-service.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows Identity Foundation in your role?

Check out this blog post I wrote which explains the problem I was having with Access Control.  More than likely you are missing the WIF dll's up in Azure after deployment.  The dll's for WIF need to be in the GAC.  You can also use Intellitrace to figure out why the role isn't starting up.

http://blog.cloudish.net/the-cloudish-blog/2012/3/28/how-to-install-the-windows-identity-foundation-runtime-on-de.html

Comment: I also want to point out that the best way to diagnose an issue in Azure is to use Intellitrace vs trying to RDP into the virtual server.

Comment: I've never heard of Intellitrace before, I'll have to look into it. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your cert problem, are you sure you added it as a service certificate and not a management certificate?

You might also want to check out the identity developer training kit. It has a step by step lab called "Web Services and Identity in Windows Azure" which demonstrates how to create and deploy a WIF powered website to azure. You should take a look at the certificate portions to ensure everything is correct on your end, both in your dev fabric instance and in azure.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14347